# C++ Visual Studio Code Not Compiling with Individual Folders in Workspaces

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, workspace

I'm new to Visual Studio Code. I'm setting up a workspace with multiple folders to create individual projects using the same .vs code under the root. Unless my .cpp and .h files are under the root folder, I get compile errors:

> g++.exe: error: main.cpp: No such file or directory

and

> g++.exe: fatal error: no input files

In other words, if I add files to a subfolder under the root of the workspace - or even copy the `.vscode` folder to each subfolder - it will not compile and I get this error.

I have messed around with the `launch.json` and `settings.json` files, to no avail.

Here is the `launch.json` configuration:

```
{
    "name": "(gdb) Launch",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.exe",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": true,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
    "preLaunchTask": "echo",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to be able to use the same `.vscode` settings under the root folder for all subfolder projects that also contain c++ code for each. Is this even possible? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check `tasks.json` and not `launch.json` as `tasks.json` has the configuration for compilation of your source code.

In `tasks.json` you can mention relative path of your source code.

And each time you need to compile a source file, you need to edit `tasks.json` and `launch.json`

You can work in a way where you put `.vscode` folder in a root workspace and have source code in your sub folders.